# SAP UI5 Modifying an Odata model obtained from manifest before setModel()

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am creating my first SAP UI5 app and I have a need where i want to set an additional property to the data returned from an Odata service before i set it as a model to in the table view

However i am unable to access the data as the getProperty returns an empty object. Below is the code on the onInit() method of my controller . I am obtaining the model from my manifest.json as it looks a clean way to do things.

```
var rList = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("Entities");
var localPromise = this.getPromise(rList, "/");
localPromise.done(function() {
    console.log(rList.getProperty("/"));
    // here i would like to do the manipulations and then set the view      
 }.bind(this));
},
```

i assume the getPromise method must take care of the asynchronous execution part:

```
getPromise: function(oModel, pathToTestForData) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            if (oModel.getProperty(pathToTestForData))
                deferred.resolve(); //Data already loaded
            else
                oModel.attachRequestCompleted(deferred.resolve); //Waiting for the event
            return deferred.promise();
        }
```

What i want to do is the following:

1) make the Odata two way bind.

2)  set another property : `anotherProperty : false` on each returned Odata record

However as  `rList.getProperty("/")`   inside the done of the promise is empty, i am at a roadblock, Also how to access the data (if it was there)

Comment: Part of the problem could be that you shouldn't do it in the onInit(). Your view isn't ready when the onInit() is called

Comment: @ChrisNeve , thanks a lot , well yeah that problems can arise when i am assigning it to view, However i am confused with just accessing the model in the resolved promise its empty . I just tried to ` oView.setModel(rList)` inside the done of the promise and it assigns correctly.  If not on onInit() where should the model be ideally assigned to the view ?